# Are there pipes above a toilet in a typical residential bathroom?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, toilet, nailing

We have a new-build house. I’d like to hang some pictures behind the toilet, but I’m not sure where the pipes run in the bathroom. Is there any chance they run vertically above the toilet? I can’t seem to find a good answer online.

The toilet is mounted to the floor, against an interior wall.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a floor above? What is up there if there is one?

Comment: Good question, it’s just a 1 story house! No floor above.

Comment: It is possible, but if there is a basement, it might let you how the pipes are running.  People are lazy so they usually will use floor joists to run pipes, instead of the attic/ceiling.

Comment: Is there _any_ chance? Yes, there is a chance. It's not likely, but there is a chance. Where in the world do you live? Can you ask the builder for drawings for the house - the actual wiring & plumbing layouts will likely be reasonably close to what's on the drawings. Do you have a basement, crawlspace or slab?

Comment: There is no basement or crawlspace. We live in Texas, and it’s basically a cookie-cutter house from a huge home builder. I’ll definitely check with them next week about any drawings (we weren’t provided with any when we moved in). I’d already put a nail in the wall before thinking about this, so I suddenly realized I should find out if I should be worried or not haha.

Comment: The stack/vent could be there. Presumably the supply lines are in/  below the concrete pad. I have a water heater in the attic so I have some supply lines in the walls.

Comment: My house was custom ; there is no drawing of the plumbing. The plumbing contractor put the lines where he wanted.

Comment: Ah okay interesting. Just as some more info, our hot water heater is in the garage. Not sure where exactly the pipes run in/out of it. Hopefully I can get plumbing plans from the builder.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the above comments- single story/ slab foundation/ WH is in garage you are most likely OK plumbing pipe wise- **but** there may be electrical wires/ AC lines/ etc. in there as well. Probably safest to find the studs and jiust attach there with screws or nails that don't go into the wood studs more than  1" or   1 1/4". Any wiring closer than that to the stud side of the drywall *should* have a metal nail plate over it.

Truth is that no one can tell what is in your walls- probably not even your builder unless there were pre-drywall pictures taken of the entire house (which is easy these days and highly recommended).

Comment: Bro, you don't need to find studs to put up some family photos.

Answer (score 1):

You are overthinking this. It doesn't matter. If you are hanging ordinary pictures, like a 5x7 of your family or something, it doesn't matter where the pipes are.

You'll be using pretty small nails that probably wont even go all the way through the drywall. You could hang a picture in the exact spot of a pipe behind and not have a problem.

Unless your pictures weigh 50 pounds per fastener or more, this is all a non issue.